# Parsing URL variables after htaccess edits

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So this one has me stumped...

I have my htaccess set up so when a user types in a name(given that it's correct), it redirects the browser to the correct file (ie http://localhost/mgo/barbis) That works fine. When I use variables in the URL (ie http://localhost/mgo/barbis?page=menu&temp=1, it still works fine because of how I'm parsing the data. But when I want to pull the `$_GET` variables out of the string, it doesn't work.

I have tried `var_dump($_GET)` and it shows me that the only existing variable is `[id]=>barbis`.

I know a viable solution would be to capture the data after the "?" (`SERVER_URI, substr, strpos, etc`) and explode in to an array but I'm curious if this is just something simple that I'm missing.

I don't know if it matters but for good measure, here's my htaccess layout.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mgo/modules/menu/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1

<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 /mgo/404.php
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mgo/modules/menu/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**With [QSA]:** When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

And with `/?` work with or without final `/`

Comment: Amazing - thank you! I figured it was something silly and that is the perfect solution. Thanks again!